# JS "If & else" does not respond properly

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, var

I am trying to make a site which will display various sentences depending on the variable "d". 
The plan is if "d" is exactly 0, the first line will be displayed, as well as the value of d will be displayed in the paragraph with a class of "text".

[This is the code](https://jsfiddle.net/psykmk1o/)

```
    <!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="Ubuntu">
<nav>
  <div>
    <h1>Beregn antal diskriminanter</h1>
  </div>
</nav>

<div align="center" class="main_container">
  <table>
    <form method="POST" name="diskriminant" action="diskriminant.html">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p> Indtast a </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="numA" size="6" class="input-form"/></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p> Indtast b </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="numB" size="6" class="input-form"/></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p> Indtast c </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" name="numC" size="6" class="input-form"/></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <p><input type="button"  name="knap" value="Beregn" onkeydown="enter()" onclick="beregner()"class="button Ubuntu"/></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <p id="text" class="align"></p> <br> <p id="result" class="align"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
    </form>
  </table>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
<script>
    function beregner() {
        var a;
        var b;
        var c;
        var d;
        var res;

        a=document.diskriminant.numA.value;
        b=document.diskriminant.numB.value;
        c=document.diskriminant.numC.value;

        d=Math.pow(( +b),2)-4*a*c;


        if (d = 0) {
          res = "Der er ingen nulpunkter";
        }
        else if (d < 0) {
            res ="Der er et nulpunkt";
          }
        else {
            res ="Der er to nulpunkter";
          }


          document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=+d;
          document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=res;


    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `==` is equality comparer in js. `=` assigns a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparisons are evaluated using the `==` operator in JavaScript. Simply alter your `if-statement`:

```
if (d == 0) {
    res = "Der er ingen nulpunkter";
}
```

Comment: I apperciate it :))

Answer (score 1):

Well `d = 0` is not the same as `d == 0`. This is your problem, your are assigning a value to variable here.
Variable assignment always returns true.

Answer (score 1):

`d = 0` is assigning a variable. try `if (d === 0)`

Answer (score 1):

To be on the safe side, always use "===" operator since it checks both types and values. This way you'll truly know if two things are equal.